# Mule 4 FTP: how to store XML data in driveHQ?

Tags: xml, ftp, mulesoft, mule4

In mule 4 I am consuming a SOAP web service WSDL and fetching XML data which I require and storing it into a variable. This part is running perfectly. Then I am trying to store the XML data in driveHQ.com through the FTP connector. The connection is successful, but I am not able to store the data because I don't know how to do it. Need help. It is showing "Cannot convert given path into a valid Uri"

Answer (score 0):

Error message stays that url what you are using is incorrect. Probably you had included id:password to it or mistype it. Double check the url. Better Log it with some Logger to see the actual one.

Hope it helps
-- Creating Mulesoft apps at [smimleflatservice.com](https://simpleflatservice.com)